YouTube Data API: 'Quota Exceeded' Error Despite Not Reaching Daily Limit
I'm working on a Google Apps Script that uploads videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3. I've encountered a quotaExceeded error when attempting to upload a video, but my quota usage shows only about 64% of the daily 10,000-unit limit.
Here's a summary of the issue:
Daily Quota: 10,000 units, with only ~6,400 used.
API Response:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}



I’ve reviewed my quotas on Google Cloud Console, and they seem within limits. I also confirmed there are no spikes in the API request rate (e.g., "Queries per 100 seconds").
My questions:
Are there any hidden quotas or undocumented limitations with the YouTube Data API v3 that I might be hitting?
Is there a way to monitor or optimize API usage more effectively to avoid this issue?
If the issue is due to upload-specific quotas (like "uploads per day"), is there a workaround, or do I need to request a quota increase?
Here’s a portion of my code where the upload process initiates (using Google Apps Script):

function initiateYouTubeUpload(fileName, title, description) {
  var accessToken = getYouTubeAccessToken();
  if (!accessToken) {
    throw new Error('YouTube access token fetch failed');
  }
  
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=snippet,status';
  var metadata = {
    snippet: {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      tags: ['sample'],
      categoryId: '22'
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: 'private'
    }
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'X-Upload-Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    },
    payload: JSON.stringify(metadata),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 || response.getResponseCode() === 201) {
    return response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  } else {
    throw new Error('Failed to initiate YouTube upload: ' + response.getContentText());
  }
}


This question is similar to: YouTube: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
